# How to create a SQL Server database using dBeaver?

Tags: sql-server, dbeaver

How to create a database in SQL Server 2014 using the dBeaver GUI tool?

[image: Screenshot from dBeaver]

Comment: `CREATE DATABASE YourDatabase` is the minimal code required.

Comment: How do you set up international collation? such as unicode, utf ... ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It isn't supported yet, as [devs explain](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/2674):

> Database create not yet supported for SQL Server (will be added as a part of [#810](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/810)).

Answer (score 5):

You can create database by commands like below:

```
--create where
USE master;  
GO
--check if exists
IF DB_ID (N'MyDatabaseTest') IS NULL  
DROP DATABASE MyOptionsTest;  
GO 
--create database 
CREATE DATABASE MyDatabaseTest  
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  
WITH TRUSTWORTHY ON, DB_CHAINING ON;  
GO
--Verifying collation and option settings.  
SELECT name, collation_name, is_trustworthy_on, is_db_chaining_on  
FROM sys.databases  
WHERE name = N'MyOptionsTest';  
GO
```

If you want to delete existing one, use below command:

```
IF DB_ID (N'MyDatabaseTest') IS NOT NULL  
DROP DATABASE MyDatabaseTest;
```

Comment: still not supported. See ticket -> [github issue](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/2330)

Comment: still not supported :)

Answer (score 2):

##### Answer

Just to make this clear for anyone wondering how to create a database in DBeaver:

*You cannot create a database in DBeaver.*

This is already the answer to the question.

##### Beyond the answer

You can only connect to a database that is already there.

What is more, DBeaver does not install the database driver that you need to make the needed database when you make a new connection. DBeaver only installs the drivers for the DBeaver GUI (Graphical User Interface), that is what you see running at a cold start. You need to download and install the database driver yourself and set up a database yourself. Just make a new one in the console or in another GUI. Taking up the comment from above:

> `CREATE DATABASE YourDatabase` is the minimal code required.

And only then, you can connect to it:

[image]

With the host, port, database, username and password that depends on your settings outside of DBeaver.

I did this only for PostgreSQL, but it should be the same for SQL Server. Before I had installed PostgreSQL, DBeaver threw:

> Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. Connection refused: connect

After installing [PostgreSQL](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads), DBeaver said that it did not know the databases, but the error was gone. After making the database with *pgAdmin 4*, I could see everything in DBeaver as well.